# Поблочная передача файла.С++

Tags: visual-c++

Задача: Клиент посылает серверу запрос, содержащий путь искомого файла и размер блока  на который должен разбиваться файл.
Сервер ищет файл и поблочно пересылает файл, записываемый клиентом (в случае отсутствия искомого файла выдается сообщение об ошибке).

Как поблочно передать файл?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
открыть файл
пока не конец файла
{
    прочитать нужный блок
    отправить блок
}
закрыть файл
```